# React useState - setting initial state to prefilled value

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with an input component that may be empty or it may be prefilled with some data. It's also a controlled component so I keep track of the value of the input field using React's `useState`.

Something like this:

```
export const MyComponent = props => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value || null)

    return <input value={value} type="text" />
}
```

In reality, however, prefilling the initial state of the input field is a bit more complex as there is a bit more drilling I have to do in the `props` argument and some checks that I have to do before initializing the default value.

Now, I can do this:

```
export const MyComponent = props => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.one?.two?.[0].value !== 0) {
            const option = props.someList.find(x => x.id === props.one.two[0].value)
            if (option)
                setValue(option)
        }
    }, [])

    return <input value={value} type="text" />
}
```

But I get warnings saying that useEffect has missing dependencies and I should add the `props` drilldown to my dependencies array. But I don't want to have the `useEffect` run every single time that is updated. I just want to have it run once upon component mount / initialization and that's it.

Is there a way to do my complicated initialization without having to use `useEffect`?

Comment: This is an eslint error warning. You can suppress it. That's what usually is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value to `useState` can be a function. You can put the logic there instead of in a `useEffect`.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(getInitialValue)

const getInitialValue = () => {
  if (props.one?.two?.[0].value !== 0) {
    const option = props.someList.find(x => x.id === props.one.two[0].value)
    if (option) {
      return option;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Notice that it was not `useState(getInitialValue())`. Passing the function for React to call means it will only be called once. Calling it yourself will cause it to happen every render.